# 回答の締め切りをすることはできますか？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問の案

他のサイトで言う「回答の締め切り」をすることはできますか？

クローズという機能が使えるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

そのような機能はありません。

あなたの疑問が解決したらそれで終了ではなく、よりよい方法が見つかれば回答を編集・追加するなどして、将来にわたって役立つQ&Aとして維持していくのがこのサイトの方針です。

そのため、

- [ある程度回答がついた質問の削除](/help/deleted-questions)
- [質問のクローズ](/help/privileges/close-questions)等の回答禁止措置
  <sub>クローズは既存の質問と重複している、このサイトに適さない、回答しようがない、といった質問に対して使うもので、一定の信用度を持つ（サイトに慣れている）ユーザーの投票によって決定されます。</sub>

は質問者でもできないようになっています。

質問が解決した際は、役に立った回答に承認やプラス投票をしたり、自力で解決した場合はそれを自己回答して、質問はそのまま残しておいてください。

参考 [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか? - ヘルプセンター](/help/someone-answers)

※著作権や個人情報関連の問題があるなど、どうしても削除しなければならない場合は、質問下にある[通報]リンクからモデレーターにお知らせいただくか、[お問い合わせ](/contact)からご連絡ください。